# Docker Plugin error: failed to fetch metadata: fork/exec %plugin_path%: permission denied

Tags: docker, gitlab

I loaded the 'sbom' plugin for Docker and it works fine running manually and from root.  However, in trying to integrate generating sboms in my GitLab deployment pipeline, the account that executes my job, 'gitlab-runner', on my GitLab Runner (RHEL VM), the command fails saying 'sbom' is unrecognized.

When I log into the runner and su over to the 'gitlab-runner' user, running 'docker' with no options, provides command output and it shows sbom but says it's an invalid plugin and shows this error:

```
Invalid Plugins:
  sbom        failed to fetch metadata: fork/exec /home/gitlab-runner/.docker/cli-plugins/docker-sbom: permission denied
```

...and other Docker commands work fine running as 'gitlab-runner' (e.g. build, images, ps, etc.)

I've checked ownership and permissions and they look fine (compared them to the working plugin file in root's home).  I can get rid of the error by deleting the plugin from the path above.  However, when I try to reinstall, the same file comes down, gets installed, and throws the same error.

Here's the reference doc:  https://docs.docker.com/engine/sbom/